# Why is this the wrong?(python)

Tags: python-3.x

```
with open("info.txt", "r") as file:
for line in file:
    (name, weight, height) = line.strip().split(", ")
    if (not name) or (not weight) or (not height):
        continue

    
    bmi = int(weight) / ((int(height) / 100) **2)
    result = ""
    if 25 <= bmi:
        result = "과체중"
    elif 18.5 <= bmi:
        result = "정상 체중"
    else:
        result = "저체중"


    print('\n'.join([
        "이름: {}",
        "몸무게: {}",
        "키: {}",
        "BMI: {}",
        "결과: {}"
    ]).format(name, weight, height, bmi, result))
    print()
```

**error message:**

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\Users\cnhan\My_project\python\tempCodeRunnerFile.py", line 4, in 
(name, weight, height) = line.strip().split(", ")
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 3)

Comment: Please provide a better title for your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check what is the length of array returned by `line.strip().split(", ")`. The error occured because it returned **more than 3 values** (name, weight, height).

If it happens that some lines may return more than 3 values, but you want **only the first three** then you can add the `*` operator in the end.

Like this

```py
(name, weight, height, *_) = line.strip().split(", ")
```